# Trying to copy files from former Ubuntu installation (WSL) on Windows 10 and overwrite more recent installation, using rsync - permission errors

Tags: permissions

```
$ sudo rsync -av --chown=root:root --no-perms --rsync-path="sudo rsync" ~/ext4.vhdx "/mnt/c/Users/Patrick Johnston/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/"
sending incremental file list
rsync: [Receiver] change_dir#1 "/mnt/c/Users/Patrick Johnston/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(751) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to know if any others have encountered similar problems with permissions when they have tried to restore files from an ext4.vhdx image.  I have used File Explorer to remove the Read Only designation on rootfs and its subdirectories and files as well as be certain they are Shared.  However, they all revert back to these settings once I've attempted the rsync command in Linux.  I've also taken these steps using chmod in the Ubuntu Linux environment but that hasn't worked either.